# R markdown error: non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

Code:
[image]

Error:

Quitting from lines 40-46 (Code.Rmd)
Error in ggplot(Fat) : could not find function "ggplot"
Calls:  ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

I can't convert this code into pdf, can anyone please tell me why this error had occurred and what should I do>

Comment: Put `library(ggplot2)` in your first code chunk. You need to load packages in Rmd documents.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas I did but it still doesn't work, the same error still pops up